# Get list of files(videos)in JSON file from server and download videos on order and than to play it in order also?

Tags: android, json, video-streaming, local, playback

I have a web service that stores the files at http://.mysite.com/content/videos
Now all I want to achieve in my android application is to download every videos that user can upload on this server, so i can get a json file from the server to see how many videos are stored and to download the all list locally and than to play it on a loop.
Please give me some code examples and ideas to.
The idea is building a Signage android client.

Comment: What i want to do is that getting a list of videos from the server and to download it locally and than to play it on video player, only when the downloads have finished first.

Comment: there is already tons of answer if you search..what have you tried so far? Nothing because you didnt search?

Comment: I did searched, i wrote  here to look for better guides. Sorry im just a beginner.
If u can help on a better solution or idea would be great.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For getting JSON from URL, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34691175/how-to-send-httprequest-and-get-json-response-in-android/34691486#34691486).

After that You can use [this](https://github.com/lingochamp/FileDownloader) library for downloading videos. You can also download them serial (one by one) or parallel.

**Usage:**
Initialize the downloader in Application class:

```
public XXApplication extends Application{

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();
      FileDownloader.init(this);
   }
}
```

Then download like this.

```
final FileDownloadListener queueTarget = new FileDownloadListener() {
        @Override
        protected void pending(BaseDownloadTask task, int soFarBytes, int totalBytes) {
        }

        @Override
        protected void connected(BaseDownloadTask task, String etag, boolean isContinue, int soFarBytes, int totalBytes) {
        }

        @Override
        protected void progress(BaseDownloadTask task, int soFarBytes, int totalBytes) {
        }

        @Override
        protected void blockComplete(BaseDownloadTask task) {
        }

        @Override
        protected void retry(final BaseDownloadTask task, final Throwable ex, final int retryingTimes, final int soFarBytes) {
        }

        @Override
        protected void completed(BaseDownloadTask task) {
        }

        @Override
        protected void paused(BaseDownloadTask task, int soFarBytes, int totalBytes) {
        }

        @Override
        protected void error(BaseDownloadTask task, Throwable e) {
        }

        @Override
        protected void warn(BaseDownloadTask task) {
        }
    };


for (String url : URLS) {
   FileDownloader.getImpl().create(url)
       .setCallbackProgressTimes(0) 
       .setListener(queueTarget)
       .ready();
}

if(serial){ 
   FileDownloader.getImpl().start(queueTarget, true);
 }
```