# Base64 image data is not getting in android

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I am using `HTTPURLConnection` to connect to server and my response contains `Base64` image data. When trying to read the response using `getInputStream` its not reading the complete response, breaks in between. My response contains list of objects in JSON format and each object contains BASE64 image data. Reading breaks while trying to read the first image data from the first object. Though its not showing any error it displays till half of the image data.How do i get the full response?? Here is my code

```
InputStream is = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            byte[] b = new byte[1024];
            StringBuffer buffer=new StringBuffer();
            while ( is.read(b) != -1){
                buffer.append(new String(b));
                System.out.println("Read= "+is.read());
            }
System.out.println(buffer);
```

Comment: It is possible that since Base64 strings are long, it gets truncated when you try to log them. Try saving it in a file. You should be able to see the whole String.

Comment: @EricB. tried it but getting same result.

Comment: try method from this link to get inputStream http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654876/http-get-using-android-httpurlconnection

Comment: @VivekMishra i tried that method. Now am getting some more data but again it fails to read.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the example code from [Google](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)?

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.android.com/");
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
try {
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
    readStream(in);
} finally {
    urlConnection.disconnect();
}
```

where `readStream` is your own method.

Reading from a `BufferedInputStream` is easier and faster.