# How do i send form-data or form-urlencocded data in Kotlin Android Studio?

Tags: php, android, kotlin, android-volley

I have to send a request to an API call which takes data at :

> https://www.example.com/abc/abc/Register.php

It takes POST data such as `mobile = 1234567989` and `id = 12345` 
in Postmen the data goes in the body as `form-data` or `x-www-form-urlencoded` with keys and values.

How do I do that in android studio using kotlin?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP Request in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46177133/http-request-in-kotlin)

Answer (score 0):

Use retorfit library.Fast and easy

```
   interface YourApi {
    @POST("/examaples")
    fun getExamples(@Body requestObject:JsonObject): Call<JsonOBject>
 }
```

Your request body

```
val requestObject = JsonObject()
requestObject.addProperty("param1","value")
```

Send parameter

```
api.getExamples(requestObject).enqueue(object : Callback<JsonObject> {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call<JsonObject>, t: Throwable) {
            t.message
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<JsonObject>, response: Response<JsonObject>) {
            if (response.isSuccessful){
                val resp = response.body()
            }
        }

    })
```

Comment: sorry but can't pass the parameters as JSON objects; they need to be in form-data format.

Answer (score 0):

Interface be like (Kotlin)

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("endPoint")
suspend fun nameOfFunction(
@Field("param")parm1:String,
@Field("param")parm2:String,):Response<ModalClass>
```

its coroutines using , you can remove suspend and response from 3rd line.
Hope you got urs answer.