# Get request in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, url

How can I send a requestBody using this:

```
try {
        data =(URL("<URL>" + path).openConnection() as HttpsURLConnection).apply {
            sslSocketFactory = createSocketFactory(listOf("TLSv1.2"))
            hostnameVerifier = HostnameVerifier { _, _ -> true }
            readTimeout = 5_000
            
        }.inputStream.bufferedReader().readText()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        println("error").toString()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46179139/8073652). I highly recommend a simple library like [http4k](https://www.http4k.org/documentation/)

```
val client = JavaHttpClient()
val request = Request(Method.GET, "https://google.com")
val response = client(request)
```

Comment: is it meaningful to send a request body in a GET request ?