# Easy android https request?

Tags: android, https, request

I know, there are much posts and answers on this topic and it seems, I have read them all... But I just want to know how to do an easy https request in my Android app. Is there a easy class which make such an request?
I want to call something like

```
String response = new EasyHttpRequest().execute(myUrl).get();
```

in my MainActivity

For information I can't just set the response Text to an TextView in the onPostExecute() method, I have to work with this data and save it or something else.

Comment: in android you have different ways of calling http request..can you please elaborate more what do you want? do youwant just one line of code for http request?

Comment: For every library/ method you need to write some code, there's no easy way to do in two lines. Some libraries can help you to customize your response for the best fit in app.

Comment: I want  a AsyncTask class, which when i call it, like in the code above, returns the string response from an url...

Comment: you can use retrofit and volley for that! but you have to write some line of code for these as well!

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38593371/how-can-i-make-a-simple-http-request-in-mainactivity-java-android-studio see this!

Comment: Is it possible to do an AsyncTask in another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best library I know so far for network requests is [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/). It's kind of a standard for Android apps. If you want something more low level you can use [Okhttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp/).

Both libraries can work together, and they are more than production ready. Of course, they support https and many other security features as ssl certificate pinning.

They support running the request on the same thread you are or in a background queue provided by the library, up to you if then you want to wrap it on an asyncTask, simple thread or service, those libraries leave you some freedom in that matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this repo . it's very easy to use. 
[okhttp-utils](https://github.com/hongyangAndroid/okhttputils)