# I don't get the response code from the connection

Tags: android, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection

I'm using AsyncTask to connect to a server. I followed the post: [Http Get using Android HttpURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654876/http-get-using-android-httpurlconnection)

but I always get an IOException (return xxx -33). What am I doing wrong? going to see the apache log I see that the POST request has never been received.

```
 public abstract class SenderHttp extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    Log.i("TAG", params[0]);
    Log.i("TAG", params[1]);

    String data = "";
    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
    int responseCode=-33;
    try {
        httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(params[0]).openConnection();

        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
        httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);

        httpURLConnection.connect();
        responseCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "xxx" + " "+ responseCode;
    }
    return " "+ responseCode;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Http Get using Android HttpURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654876/http-get-using-android-httpurlconnection)

Comment: reference was made to an input stream. I need to send data to the server and I need an output stream. It's correct?

Comment: what's the output of e.printStackTrace()

Comment: W/System.err: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
at com.example.myapplication.SenderHttp.doInBackground(SenderHttp.java:40)
(the line where I do:  new DataOutputStream(httpURLConnection.getOutputStream() )

Comment: Are you using localhost url?

Comment: I connect from my smartphone locally to apache tomcat. I tried with:
http:// 172.16.95.101:8080/servlet or http:// 192.168.42.232:8080/servlet

Comment: Are you able the ping the smartphone IP from your pc

Comment: Just make sure the problems lies within the android code, which for me seems to be okay

Comment: I'm not sure. I use ipconfig from dos. are there other ways?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200357/discussion-between-saurav-kumar-and-antilope).